# iFrame load event triggering on localhost but not on server

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, rhel

I have an iFrame, which loads some content from some URL of same origin. On load event of this iFrame, I have some javascript. This works fine on my local windows machine, but when I upload code to my server based on RHEL, IFrame onload event is not triggered at all! I am wondering, what could be possible reasons for this.

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com/foo" id="hid-if"></iframe>

<script>
 (function () {
     var
     nIframe = $.getElementById('hid-if');
     nIframe.addEventListener('load',handler,false);

     function handler () {
          //some work
     }

  })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost every `JavaScript project starts off with a conversation about browser compatibility`. As much as we'd like to think that JavaScript is JavaScript, each browser has its own implementation; and depending on what you're trying to do, those implementations could be `drastically different from one another`.

`Unfortunately it is not possible to use an iframe's onload event in Chrome` if the content is an attachment. Neither of these browsers provide any events for `iFrames loaded with content` that have an "Attachment" disposition type.

Click here for more info:[**Events to Expect when Dynamically Loading iFrames in JavaScript**](http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/jake/archive/2009/06/18/events-to-expect-when-dynamically-loading-iframes-in-javascript.aspx)